# cannot use the find functions using sequelize-typescript

Tags: express, sequelize.js, passport.js, sequelize-typescript

I have setup passport and sequelize-typescript for my project. In the passport setup, I use a strategy for example google like this:

```js
passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy(
        {
            clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_AUTH_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_AUTH_CLIENT_SECRET,
            callbackURL: process.env.GOOGLE_AUTH_CALLBACK_URL,
            profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'photos', 'email'],
            enableProof: true
        },
        function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
            console.log(profile)
            const { name, email, picture } = profile._json;
            
            User.findOne({where: {id: profile.id}})
            .then(user => {
                console.log(user)

                if(user === null) {
                    const { name, email, picture } = profile._json;
                    // new User({
                    //     id: profile.id,
                    //     name: name,
                    //     email: email,
                    //     pictureUrl: picture, 
                    // })
                }
            })

            done(null, profile)
        }
    )
)
```

When I try to use functions such as `findOrCreate()` or `findOne()`, I receive a typescript error that says:

```
[ERROR] 23:29:01 ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/passport_strategies.ts:45:18 - error TS2339: Property 'findOne' does not exist on type 'typeof User'.

45             User.findOne({where: {id: profile.id}})
```

I also get the same error for the part commented out in the first code snippet. The model user I have created is declared like this:
`export class User extends Model<User> {}` (It has the columns set in the file) `Model` being imported from `sequelize-typescript`

Here is where sequelize is created:

```js
export const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  "username": c.username,
  "password": c.password,
  "database": c.database,
  "host":     c.host,

  dialect: 'postgres',
  storage: ':memory:',
  models: [__dirname + '/models']
});
```

I tried checking other examples that are on the internet but they all have the same setup and I couldn't figure out why I'm getting this error. Not sure if this helps at all but I'm using postgres dialect.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that it is a version mismatch.
sequelize-typescript@2 is for sequelize@6.2>= and sequelize-typescript@1 is for sequelize@5>=.

I also suggest for educational purposes to implement typescript with sequelize without the use of the sequelize-typescript package just for understanding the need of the package itself. https://sequelize.org/master/manual/typescript.html

Also just in case with all the respect, i point that @Table is needed if you are using the latest version.